# How do I unlock Disarm and Destroy?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

In Arkham Origins, which I am absolutely loving, I can't find any way to do the classic, and often essential "Disarm and Destroy move".

This is the one where you press X + Y on Xbox, or Square + Triangle on PS3, and you punch a dude, take his weapon (knife, glowstick, shield, gun), and break it. Which means it can't be used again.

It's totally essential to combat, as bad guys become progressively more prepared throughout the game. I can't perform it by default, and there's no unlockable option for it in the Waynetech upgrade screen. I got the Double Special upgrade, which mentions in the description that you can use it with other Specials, but it still doesn't work.

Anyone else having this issue? I feel there's a small change you can't use the ability until the game tells you to i.e. I might play a mission where it will tell me to use the ability, and from there it's unlocked.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be unlocked? You have to unlock the other specials (multi-takedown and bat swarm). Why would this be any different? I don't see it anywhere in the upgrade tree so it probably won't be revealed until you reach a certain point in the game.

Comment: @AlexS [You can answer your own questions here.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) You should edit out your solution in your question and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You unlock it by doing one of the game's side missions. Really stupid they don't show you what can be unlocked, I found out about every single move in the game before this one.

You have to do Bird's side missions to do it. I've no idea who Bird is or what the side missions are like- but it's those ones we need to do.

Took me like a further two hours of playing (already at about 10-11 hours) before I saw this.

Hopefully this'll be useful to someone in the future.