# What are the full steps to Unlock Disarm and Destroy?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

Another question here has already asked [how to unlock the disarmand destroy move](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137618/how-do-i-unlock-disarm-and-destroy), as my level is too low to comment I ask the question in full.

The final step is: "by doing Bird's side missions."

What is the first step of unlocking or triggering these missions?

A note: I didn't put Bird in the question intentionally as it is a spoiler, some people may not want to know the upcoming villains by reading a question and I do not know the policy here on Spoilers.

Comment: I think you just have to reach a certain part of the story, the big meeting with all the assassins. Before I reached that part, I finished all side-missions that I could complete. After that part, new missions (including the Bird missions) were now available.

Answer (score 1):

While I had hoped this could be obtained much earlier on as it is integral upgrade to the game the full answer is as follows:

The Disarm and Destroy Upgrade is unlocked by Completing the Bird side missions, the Bird missions are triggered directly through progression of the Story after the mission in which you have to enter the Morgue, you will get a communication upon leaving.